# accessing one website from my internal network

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, website, curl

I have a very strange situation on all of my entire local network
this website can be ping(ed) from all PCs but can not be accessed.
The curl command result with openvpn you can see first in the photo and without at the second
can you advice me what to do?
network is a mixture of windows 10 11 and Linux mint and arch
connection is a fiber optics with Huawei 160s open router

[image: photo of how curl responses with and without vpn]

Comment: Maybe your DNS is not resolving it? Try running `dig <website>` with and without VPN.

Comment: dig https://azmmf.com                        

; <<>> DiG 9.18.13 <<>> https://azmmf.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 4194
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;https://azmmf.com.  IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.   900 IN SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1679898207 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 126 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)

==This is without vpn==

Comment: dig https://azmmf.com                        
; <<>> DiG 9.18.13 <<>> https://azmmf.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 35676
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: a80dfdfba6973a7f815833b6642136afb44805751d497d65 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;https://azmmf.com.  IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.   768 IN SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1679898117 1800 900 604800 86400
;; Query time: 443 msec
==Vpn=

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the `dig` output. Don't use comments for additional information.